# HTML Map that Reads from Personal Geodatabase

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-access, leaflet, geojson

I am looking for solutions on how to possibly load polygon data from an ESRI Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) to an HTML map?

***Goal***

To load a Map within a web-browser.  The map to display polygons that are read from a personal geodatabase.  This map will then be embedded into a Microsoft Access Form for the user to interact with through the web-browser.

**Options I have Explored:**

***Google Maps:***

I have looked at using google maps that reads a kml/kmz file with the polygon information from the geodatabase, but this requires me to update the kml/kmz each time a new polygon is entered. A more automated solution would be preferable.

***Leaflet***

Having researched leaflet, it appears that it is possible to load a map from a file geodatabase, but not a personal geodatabase.  Unfortunately, I am handcuffed by the personal geodatabase in this particular scenario (many users, multiple geodatabases, and Microsoft Access forms)

***ArcGIS Online***

Is it possible to have arcGIS online read from a local file each time it is opened.  I realize ArcGIS online requires a zip file, but I could automate the compression of a document. Any suggestions regarding the direction I should take this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read my problem, and providing feedback.  I really appreciate it.

Kev

Comment: Have a look at MapServer: [ESRI Personal Geodatabase (MDB) — MapServer 7.4.3 documentation](https://mapserver.org/input/vector/pgeo.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Manifold](http://www.manifold.net/)'s Export  capability can convert an entire ESRI personal geodatabase into a .map or .mxb project in a single step.

Also, we have [WPF SharpMap](http://wpfsharpmapcontrols.codeplex.com/) Controls, which is a set of WPF mapping controls which is a .Net control which you can explore to convert.

I have not tried these yet, but I just thought of giving you some ideas. Meanwhile I will also explore.